Prestashop issue after moving to another server - 302 Found sometimes with ajax
I'm working on a Prestashop web shop and it's live for a few years. Now we want to move it to another, better, VPS server. Server is configured and prepared before, then the files copied, and database imported. I point the site to a new IP on Cloudflare and the new site is active.
Almost everything works great, but I noticed one big issue with cart updates. Here we use one page checkout. When updating options like delivery options, payment methods, etc. It sends ajax request and refreshes the cart, and it works perfectly on the old server.
On the new one, it's strange, because sometimes it updates the cart with no problems, ajax request is 200. But sometimes, it doesn't. The code in console is 302 Found, and there is no response, so it doesn't refresh the cart. While testing, when changing options several times, it sometimes responds with 200, next change is 302, next maybe 200, maybe 302, etc.
I tried with cache purging in Prestashop, purged cache in Cloudflare, tried turning off/on the Cloudflare proxy, turning off/on SSL and many things I've found googling this, but no success.
When I point the domain back to the old IP address, it works perfectly again. So I really don't know what to do anymore...

On the new one, it's strange, because sometimes it updates cart with no problems, ajax request is 200. But sometimes, it doesnt. what version of Prestashop?

@GregAskew It's 1.7. Same on both, because files are zipped (tar) and moved and unpacked on other, just as the database was exported and imported.

Try to delete, stopping Web server, folders /var/www/yoursite/var/cache/prod and /var/www/yoursite/var/cache/dev
Then start your Web server and try again.
most likely it is simply a cache problem
